# How to turn on the network indicator in the iOS status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I am aware there is more than one of these indicators.
Thanks.

Comment: There are not indicators for different types of network connections other than what the users' devices already display, such as GPRS, Edge, 3G, 4G, LTE and Wi-Fi. Using the below answer will display a UIActivityIndicatorView in the status bar, which is appropriate enough when your app does networking.

Answer (score 94):

**Swift**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

**Swift 5** , **Swift 4.x** , **Swift 3.x**

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

Update for **iOS 13, 14**

There will be no network indicator displayed from iOS 13.

The [deprecation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623102-isnetworkactivityindicatorvisibl) message says:

> Provide a custom network activity UI in your app if desired.

Comment: `isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` is depracated
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623102-networkactivityindicatorvisible

Comment: @RadekWilczak Thanks for pointing out, I have addressed this deprecation.

Answer (score 64):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```